# Calculate xyz position from given index

Tags: math

I wan't to calculate an xyz position from a given index.
I'm close but not there yet.
Can someone help me, I think only my z is wrong.

```
  int w = 25;
  int h = 25;
  int d = 25;

  int max = w*h*d;

  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    int x = i % w;
    int y = ((i - x) / w)/d;
    int z = ((i - y) / w) / d ;

    println(x, y, z);
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense as written.  Are you trying to describe a 3-D matrix in a 1-D array?

Comment: all positions in a 3d box.

Comment: If you want to get all positions in the box of given w, h, d, then just do the 3 nested loops each having the test condition to be less than w, h, or d. No need to calculate max, right?

Comment: I can't use 3 loops. Yeah I could store the result in an array but that's overkill.

Answer (score 5):

Let N(i) = {0, 1, ..., i - 1}.

## A way to map 1-D to 2-D

You can map from N(AB) to N(A) × N(B) in the following way.

k ↦ (k / B, k % B)

k is the 1-D index, and (k / B, k % B) is the corresponding 2-D index.

### Example

For example, suppose you want to map from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} to {0, 1, 2} × {0, 1}.
Then A = 3 and B = 2 and you get the following mapping.

**k ↦ (x, y)**
0 ↦ (0, 0)
1 ↦ (0, 1)
2 ↦ (1, 0)
3 ↦ (1, 1)
4 ↦ (2, 0)
5 ↦ (2, 1)

## A way to map 1-D to 3-D using composition

Now if you want to map from N(ABC) to N(A) × N(B) × N(C), you can do so by using the above mapping twice: once to map from N(ABC) to N(A) × N(BC) then again to map from N(BC) to N(B) × N(C).

```
// Input: k in N(ABC)
// Output: (x, y, z) in N(A) x N(B) x N(C)

// N(ABC) -> N(A) x N(BC)
x = k / (B * C)   // x in N(A)
w = k % (B * C)   // w in N(BC)

// N(BC) -> N(B) x N(C)
y = w / C         // y in N(B)
z = w % C         // z in N(C)
```

### Example

For A = B = C = 2, this will give you the following mapping.

**k ↦ (x, y, z)**
0 ↦ (0, 0, 0)
1 ↦ (0, 0, 1)
2 ↦ (0, 1, 0)
3 ↦ (0, 1, 1)
4 ↦ (1, 0, 0)
5 ↦ (1, 0, 1)
6 ↦ (1, 1, 0)
7 ↦ (1, 1, 1)

Comment: Nice, concise answer. I find myself running into this problem a lot.

Comment: Could you make it more clear. I really don't understand it. What is k? A value between 0 and 1? And your 'code' never uses A, is that cause A is for the X axis and the length is always 1?

Comment: @clankill3r I will add more details to the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool way to get xyz from index 0..count based on size

```js
// size of side of the cube
const SIZE = 25;
// calculate volume; the number of grid cells
const COUNT = SIZE*SIZE*SIZE
// calculate the mid point of the cube
const CUBE_CENTRE = SIZE / 2
// silly way to define size of each cell
const box = {
    depth: 1,
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
}
// loop through i-COUNT and calculate xyz coords for grid cells in a cube
for(let i = 0; i < COUNT; i ++){
    const z = (i % SIZE) * box.depth - CUBE_CENTRE;
    const x = Math.floor((i / SIZE) % SIZE) * box.width - CUBE_CENTRE;
    const y = Math.floor(i / (SIZE * SIZE)) * box.height - CUBE_CENTRE;
}
```